# Why removed PPAs are still in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I remove a PPA with `add-apt-repository` for example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:bartbes/love-stable
```

but when I see the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` I still see the following files:

```
bartbes-ubuntu-love-stable-focal.list
bartbes-ubuntu-love-stable-focal.list.save
```

Why aren't these files removed and do I need to remove them manually?

Comment: does [this reference](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/remove-an-apt-repository-ubuntu) help?

Comment: @24601 It doesn't point out why these files are not deleted if they're removed from APT repository

Comment: Did you check the contents of those files? They're likely just comments now.

Comment: @muru You're right I checked the content and these files are empty now